# Enlarging the whole PDF book by 20%

Tags: geometry, article, paper-size

I'm using the krantz book template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/krantz-book-template/vfrsjggghjcd) in writing a pdf, the code is below:

```
\documentclass[krantz1,ChapterTOCs]{krantz}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,fix-cm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}


%\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}

\frenchspacing
\tolerance=5000

\makeindex

\include{frontmatter/preamble} %place custom commands and macros here

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{Quantitative Approaches to Evaluating Climate Change Impacts... 
%in Socio-Environmental Systems, Public Health, and Insurance\\
%{\Large(Applied Environmental Statistics Series)}
}
\author{Yours Truly}

\maketitle

%\include{frontmatter/dedication}
%\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{7} %previous pages will be reserved for frontmatter to be added in later.
\tableofcontents
%\include{frontmatter/foreword}
%\include{frontmatter/preface}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%\include{frontmatter/contributor}
%\include{frontmatter/symbollist}

\mainmatter

\part{Ecosystem-base Impacts of Climate Change}
\include{chapters/chapter1/ch1}
%\include{chapters/chapter2/ch2}

\part{Climate Risks in Public Health and Epidemiology}

\part{Socio-economic Impacts of Climate Adaptation and Resilience}



\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibtex_example}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

It output like this:

[image]

My question is,  is there anyway to add a something (like package geometry, etc) so that the output PDF is excatly enlarged by 20% (just enlarge the pdf, without affecting the links or others), like below?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short TeX code. Your given link needs an account :-(

Comment: you can scale the pdf on printing, or use pdf tooks to re-save it with 20% magnification

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've tried using scaling the pdf on printing, but the problem is all the links (e.g. table of contents, citations, hyperrefs,etc) on pdf will becoming invalid, therefore I'm coming to ask if there's any 'latex way' to handle this

Comment: @DavidCarlisle comment certainly works for print to paper. But as OP just commented, it is not likely to work for "print to file" PDF->PDF. May depends on software and platform. Perhaps there is "pro" software that can do that? Or not.

Comment: If you enlarge the page size a 20%, the margins and font size proportionally,  the result will be not the "exactly" the same, but it will be  fully functional. If that matter a lot, a fine tuning of margins, font size, interline spacing, paragraph skips, etc. could obtain a very close results, but always something could be  on the limit of some penalty and change unexpectedly by a minimal change.

Answer (score 1):

I would use ConTeXt for this. I have understood it as if you want to

- Scale the whole pdf (enlarge it by 20%)
- Keep links.

Let me give you one example, where you in fact need the second file and you need to set up the width and the height of the paper to fit your needs. I only use the first file as my test document.

**The file I want to include**

We make a 10cm x 10cm test file. We use a tight style and just add a table of contents and some dummy chapters.

```
\definepapersize
  [square]
  [width=10cm,
   height=10cm]

\setuppapersize
  [square]

\setuplayout[tight]

\setupinteraction
  [state=start]

\starttext

\completecontent

\dorecurse{9}{%
  \startchapter[title={Foo #1}]
    \samplefile{knuthmath}
  \stopchapter}

\stoptext
```

Compile with `context`(comes with TeXLive 2023). Output is not so interesting, but scaled to 75% it looks like this:

[image: the test document]

Clicking on the green links will make us jump to the correct chapter.

**The file that includes the other file**

This is the interesting file for you.

```
\definepapersize
  [Square]
  [width=12cm,
   height=12cm]

\setuppapersize
  [Square]

\setuplayout
  [page]

\setupinteraction
  [state=start,
   focus=standard]

\setupexternalfigure
  [interaction=all]

\starttext

\filterpages[231010-1.pdf]

\stoptext
```

All you need to do in your case is to setup the correct page size for your document and to change the name in the `\filterpages` macro. The different setups are just enabling interaction, also in inserted files. Again, compile the file with `context`. The output looks like this (zoomed to 66%)

[image: scaled result]

The pages indeed have a size of 12cm x 12cm, and everything is enlarged by 20%. The links are still clickable.

(I also tried to insert a longer document generated by LaTeX, and yes, that also worked.)